# How do I efficiently insert a list into a sorted vector while maintaining order?

Tags: c++, concatenation, stl-algorithm

I want to insert the contents of an STL list into an existing vector, so that the vector is still sorted after the insertions.

Following is the code which I am trying to do it efficiently. Though it will work, I believe there should be a much better way of concatenating.

Vector `V` does has some elements prior to described merge operation.

```
Size(V) > Size(L)
```

If this information helps anymore.

```
void merge(std::list<int>& L, std::vector<int>& V) {
    for (auto& x : L) V.push_back(x);
    std::sort(V.begin(), V.end());
}
```

The code needs to be in C++14.

Comment: `V.insert(V.end(), L.begin(), L.end());` See [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

Comment: We know the size of the list L to be concatenated, won't that help in anyway?

Comment: I believe this information is lost in `std::vector::insert` in this case since `std::distance` is not constant time with `list`'s iterators. Perhaps you can call `V.reserve(V.size() + L.size());` and see if it helps.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux gave a correct answer in this case that is the optimal solution. In case of calling push_back manually you can reallocate vector multiple times, range based insert will make sure this will happen only once.

Comment: The fact the vector is sorted matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this with `vector::insert` although I don't believe the implementation can efficiently get the distance from two bidirectional iterators so you may wish to reserve space to avoid unwanted vector resizing. At least since C++11 it appears that `list::size` must be constant time, so if you're at least on that version you can simply reserve enough space up front. Otherwise since you know that `V` is bigger than `L` just double the capacity of `V` before `insert`ing:

```
V.reserve(V.size() + L.size());
V.insert(V.end(), L.begin(), L.end());
```

Comment: Although OP accepted your answer, I altered his question noting how he explained what he _really_wants is the sorted version of that vector. FYI.

Comment: This code assumes that the list is in the same order and is greater in elements than the original vector yet the original question stated, "...so that the vector is still sorted after the insertions" which this does not guarantee. The solution below guarantees this and is efficient  (in that it does not resort the original vector).

Comment: I missed when the question got edited to change the requirements from concatenation to adding elements while keeping the container sorted. Obviously the other answer solves the new question better so I'll delete this (edit: can't delete accepted answer).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your vector was sorted and is to remain sorted, this:

```
void merge(std::list<int> const& L, std::vector<int>& V) {
  auto old_end = V.size();
  V.insert( V.end(), L.begin(), L.end() );
  std::sort( V.begin()+old_end, V.end() );
  std::inplace_merge( V.begin(), V.begin()+old_end, V.end() );
}
```

may be relatively optimal.  (Note that inplace_merge may allocate, so this may not be as optimal as one might hope)

`.insert` is guaranted to reserve space and only reallocate at most once.

Next, we sort only the elements from the list, then we do an inplace merge to merge it with the previously sorted elements in the front of the vector.

I also made the `list` a `const&`, as we are not modifying it.

Comment: `inplace_merge` may allocate, so this is probably worth benchmarking.

Comment: I like this one more!

Comment: If `insert` is guaranteed to allocate at most once, doesn't that imply two iterations over `L` to get the size of the items to insert before actually doing the work?

Comment: @MarkB Yes, that is true.  But unless the list is huge (like, cache-breaking huge), the first pass with cache the elements, the second will read out of that cache.  So no huge loss.  In theory, a manual `.reserve(.size)` followed by converting the iterators into input iterators (!) could be faster, or a manual loop where the compiler works out that the `push_back` doesn't need to check bounds (sigh, we need that method).  I suspect most optimal would be to copy the list into a temporary vector, sort that, then carefully merge it into the first vector.